# Ignore multiple XML headers in the RDF document while processing it with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, rdf

I have an RDF document with mutilple RDF records (about 30000 records in total). File creator probably by mistake added XML header before each record. It's looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<rdf:RDF>...</rdf:RDF>
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<rdf:RDF>...</rdf:RDF>
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<rdf:RDF>...</rdf:RDF>
```

I have developed an XSLT crosswalk to convert this document into different XML format, but it does not work because of that multiple headers:

```
parser error : XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
```

My test crosswalk looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"   
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:oai="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/"  
  xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
  xmlns:rss="http://my.netscape.com/rdf/simple/0.9/"
  xmlns="http://ands.org.au/standards/rif-cs/registryObjects"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs xsi xsl oai rdf rss">

  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <OAI-PMH 
    xmlns="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/ http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/OAI-PMH.xsd">

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="rdf:RDF/rss:Researcher" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="rdf:RDF/rss:Researcher">
      <oai:Researcher>
        <xsl:value-of select="rss:title" />
      </oai:Researcher>
    </xsl:template>

  </OAI-PMH>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Is it possible to somehow ignore these headers? I use xsltproc to apply the crosswalk.

Comment: XSLT processors are adamant about well-formed XML which your raw version is not. Try using general scripting (Java, PHP, Python) to open the text file and remove the duplicate headers.

Comment: Of course, it would be more simple to remove `xml prolog` from a text editor. Then you can apply your `xslt`. By the way not sure of your use case, whether it is needed automatic or just for one time and happy to edit thru text editor of your choice.

Comment: Also worth noting is that even when you remove the duplicate headers, your file still won't be legal XML, as it will still have multiple root elements.

Comment: Yeah, I end up creating Java program to split rdf into multiple xml's